# Multiple Authorization Server

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-session, spring-oauth2

I have a Zuul Proxy that host behind it all Micro services including UI and Authorization servers .

All are part of spring cloud.

I tried to start a second Authorization Servers but that lead to the below errors

```
2017-11-17 08:07:47.146  INFO 9652 --- [http-nio-9191-exec-2] o.s.s.o.p.token.store.JdbcTokenStore     : Failed to find access token for token 08fa5f86-4bbd-4e5b-818b-a79730232f30
2017-11-17 08:07:47.146 DEBUG 9652 --- [http-nio-9191-exec-2] p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid access token: 08fa5f86-4bbd-4e5b-818b-a79730232f30"
2017-11-17 08:07:47.147 DEBUG 9652 --- [http-nio-9191-exec-2] s.s.o.p.e.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer : Written [error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid access token: 08fa5f86-4bbd-4e5b-818b-a79730232f30"] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@3c3df936]
```

also

```
2017-11-17 07:39:51.151 DEBUG 9652 --- [http-nio-9191-exec-3] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Clearing scope of incoming token request
2017-11-17 07:39:51.178 DEBUG 9652 --- [http-nio-9191-exec-3] .s.s.o.p.c.AuthorizationCodeTokenGranter : Getting access token for: acme
2017-11-17 07:39:51.204  INFO 9652 --- [http-nio-9191-exec-3] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: InvalidGrantException, Invalid authorization code: Pb3JKA
2017-11-17 07:40:04.797 DEBUG 9652 --- [http-nio-9191-exec-4] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /oauth/token
2017-11-17 07:40:04.797 DEBUG 9652 --- [http-nio-9191-exec-4] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]
2017-11-17 07:40:04.850 DEBUG 9652 --- [http-nio-9191-exec-4] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Clearing scope of incoming token request
```

My conclusion was I need to have a shared session management between both authorization servers like spring session even though I am using the same jdbctoken database back end.

I could not find any sample or any one talking about this so is this correct or it should work without having a shared session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that yes , shared session is needed like spring session , my first attempt did not work because I had mixed configuration between both servers.

After that just enabling shared session management, it all worked perfectly